# Managing specificity with BEM in multilingual websites

Tags: css, css-selectors, internationalization, bem

For styling languages, it seems like it's common practice to use `[lang=en]` (or `:lang(en)`).

However, this convention can cause issues with BEM modifiers especially. Consider this CSS:

```
.block__element {
  font-size: 12px;
}

[lang=ar] .block__element {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.block__element--small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

In this event, if we have `block__element` with `lang` that isn't `ar`, it would have font size 12px. If it also has the modifier `--small`, it will have font size 10.

However, if the page's `lang` is `ar`, the font size will be 14px *regardless of modifier*. This is due to CSS's specificity.

So to counter this, a developer could add a new rule, which would simply revert it `block__element--small` in Arabic to 10px:

```
.block__element {
  font-size: 12px;
}

[lang=ar] .block__element {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.block__element--small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

// ^ Basically the same as this but more specific
[lang=ar] .block__element--small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

This is far from ideal.

Is there a more clever way to manage this situation in order to avoid overriding styles for every such case? (Which especially for RTL+LTR projects, can be extremely common)

Comment: Atleast with a CSS preprocessor it would be easier to maintain

Comment: @SuperDJ You're right, and I do use a CSS preprocessor usually. I had to resort to creating an `all-languages` mixin in one project because of this :(

Comment: I don't have the solution you need but with [this alternative BEM syntax](https://paleo.casa/pleasant-bem.html) the issue is bypassed because modifiers have a higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ideal solution here :( So your solution is not that bad.

Another could be to prefix all modifiers with an attribute selector to equalize selector weights. For example:

```css
.block__element {
  font-size: 12px;
}

[lang=ar] .block__element {
  font-size: 14px;
}

[lang] .block__element--small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This was a route we went with for a project. It worked, except we occasionally run into specificity issues when we forgot to add this. :(